# Connecting $1997$ points in the plane- what am I missing?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, plane-geometry

I know I am missing something in this problem, but I don't know what:

> Let $P_1, P_2, ..., P_{1997}$ be distinct points in the plane. Connect the points with the line segments $P_1P_2, P_2P_3, P_3P_4, ..., P_{1996}P_{1997}, P_{1997}P_{1}$. Can one draw a line that passes through the interior of every one of these segments?

According to how I understand the problem, the solution is easy. It's clearly not possible to have one line pass through every line segment in this picture.

[image]

Comment: So you have shown that it is *not always* possible. could it be *sometimes* possible?

Comment: Are you interpreting the question incorrectly or am I? 'Can one draw a line that passes through the *interior* of every one of these segments?' - I'd take that to mean the area inside.

Comment: What does line mean  here ? if corners are allowed into  line so solution  clearly is  $$  P_1P_2, P_2P_3, P_3P_4, ..., P_{1996}P_{1997}, P_{1997}P_{1} $$

Comment: Line probably refers to an infinitely long and straight one.

Comment: @Shuri2060 I think I was wrong. Possibility should depend on the parity of the number of points, and i don't think it works for an odd number...

Comment: @Shuri2060: How do you want to do it for 3 lines?

Comment: Hint: the number of points on one side of the line must be equal to the number of points on the other side.

Comment: @Henrik The quoted question says 'interior'. Doesn't that mean the area bounded inside?

Comment: No, you can prove that for $2k+1$ non-colinear points (that is, such that no three points are colinear) one line cannot pass through the interiors of an odd number of the segments, and since there are an odd number of segments, one line cannot pass through the interiors of all of them.  For some sets of $2k$ non-colinear points you can have such a line. BTW, "interior" of a line segment is the span of the *line* (not area) between the two endpoints.

Comment: @Henrik Right, that's what I'm saying... it can't work for three lines. But for four lines, you can make something consisting of two sides and two diagonals of a rectangle.

Comment: @MarkFischler: But the question doesn't specify that the points are in general position (i.e. no three are co-linear).

Comment: @MarkFischler - Thanks for clearing up my confusion. Yes, that makes sense, in which case the question isn't trivial if the answerer has to consider cases.

Comment: @Shuri2060: It says "interior of ... line segments", so no, this is not about the area bounded inside. And it also says "...interior of every one of...", that's clearly plural, so it can't be about one area. And it's trivial to find a line passing through an area.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah okay, so I guess the problem could be reformulated as "find neccesary and sufficient (or at least sufficient) conditions such that it is possible"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the hint, but I'm trying to understand the problem statement itself. Could the problem be reformulated as "find neccesary and sufficient (or at least sufficient) conditions such that it is possible to draw a line through all the segments"?

Comment: @Ovi the better statement of the problem would be: Can you distribute 1997 points on the plane such that if one connects $P_iP_{i+1}$ and $P_{1997}P_1$ then there exists a line crossing each open (meaning the points excluded) segment. I suggest you start with three points instead of 1997...

Comment: @Hamed Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider such a collection of points ${<}P_i{>}$ as described with $N$ points.

Now let us assume that a line can be drawn crossing each of the line segments ${<}L_i{>}$ where $L_N$ connects $P_N$ and $P_{1}$ and all other $L_i$ connect $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$.

Now we know that if $P_i$ is one one side of the line, $P_{i+1}$ is on the other side of the line, and $P_1$ and $P_N$ are on opposite sides of the line. We can thus infer that $N$ is even, since all odd points are on the same side of the line as $P_1$.

Thus when such a line can be drawn, $N$ must be even, and by contrapositive, if $N$ is odd, such a line cannot be drawn.